# Can't remove/reset local modifications on renamed file

Tags: git

I renamed a file because it had the wrong case, and then (later) performed a `git stash`.

After doing so, the file remained with local modifications. I've been trying to remove the changes/reset HEAD but have had no luck; git just keeps alternating between the two versions of the filename, one ending in `~iphone.storyboard` and the other `~iPhone.storyboard`.

Here's what I've tried:

#### git checkout FILE

*chopper:~/code/rio> git status*

```
On branch mrb-login-flow
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mrb-login-flow'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iPhone.storyboard

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

*chopper:~/code/rio> git checkout 'Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iPhone.storyboard'*

*chopper:~/code/rio> git status*

```
On branch mrb-login-flow
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mrb-login-flow'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iphone.storyboard

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

*chopper:~/code/rio> git checkout 'Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iphone.storyboard'*

*chopper:~/code/rio> git status*

```
On branch mrb-login-flow
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mrb-login-flow'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iPhone.storyboard

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

#### git reset --hard, git checkout -f

*chopper:~/code/rio> git reset --hard*

```
HEAD is now at 6c5c577 Join login fields into first login view
```

*chopper:~/code/rio> git status*

```
On branch mrb-login-flow
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mrb-login-flow'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iphone.storyboard

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

*chopper:~/code/rio> git reset --hard*

```
HEAD is now at 6c5c577 Join login fields into first login view
```

*chopper:~/code/rio> git status*

```
On branch mrb-login-flow
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mrb-login-flow'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iPhone.storyboard

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

#### rm

*chopper:~/code/rio> rm Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iPhone.storyboard*

*chopper:~/code/rio> git status*

```
On branch mrb-login-flow
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mrb-login-flow'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iPhone.storyboard
    deleted:    Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iphone.storyboard

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

*chopper:~/code/rio> git reset --hard*

```
HEAD is now at 6c5c577 Join login fields into first login view
```

*chopper:~/code/rio> git status*

```
On branch mrb-login-flow
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mrb-login-flow'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iPhone.storyboard

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

#### git rm -f, git mv -f (to an unrelated filename)

Similar results to `rm`, above.

#### git add

Seems to have no effect.

*chopper:~/code/rio> git add 'Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iPhone.storyboard'*

*chopper:~/code/rio> git status*

```
On branch mrb-login-flow
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mrb-login-flow'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Rio/Resources-iPhone/RIOLoginFlow~iPhone.storyboard

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48) on OS X 10.9.4

Answer (score 0):

I tar'd up the whole project and moved it over to a Linux box (git version 1.7.10.4). With a case-sensitive filesystem, I was able to clean it up, tar it up again, and move it back.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but I just had something similar and I used gitk to do a revert commit of what just happened and then did git checkout head~ files/I/Want/To/Keep/From/Original/Commit file2 file3...